# why my data isn't converting to float type , when using the split functon. #python3

Tags: python, function, split

```
u,p,k = float(input(" enter the values of viscoity, pressure , prmeability")).split(",")

l,A = int(input("enter the vaues of length and area").split(" "))


def flow_rate(u,p,k,l,A):

  Q=k* A * p/l*u

  print(f"the Q is {Q}")
flow_rate(u,p,k,l,A)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can't convert a list to a float. Try `u, p, k = map(float, input("gimme: ").split())` but don't forget to handle errors if the user doesn't enter the correct number of values. Also, when asking questions, please show the error you got. In this case, it should be `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 1 2 3'` or `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`. These errors basically tell you the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in the first line is take the whole string like "3.5,5.6,9", and try to convert that to float, and then separate it. The problem is that python can't convert a string of 3 numbers and commas into float. What you could do to solve the problem is first split the string, and then convert each element to float, like so:

```
u, p, k = map(float, input("Enter the values of viscosity, pressure, and permeability: ").split(", ")
# I changed the split separator so the input can be prettier ;)
```

Apply the same logic for the second line

Answer (score 1):

That is because you can't call `int` on a list and expect to convert values to `int`

```
input()         -> str       : "1 2 3"
input().split() -> list[str] : ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Use `map`

```
l,A = map(int, input("enter the vaues of length and area").split())
```

or a list comprehension

```
l, A = [int(x) for x in input("enter the vaues of length and area").split()]
```